# Selecting word in CBuilder

Tags: c++builder

Lets take a codeline like:

```
MyApplication->Test();
```

In Visual Studio when I press Ctrl+Shift+Right, I can get "MyApplication" selected and the retype something to replace it.
In Embaracadero's CBuilder the selection gives me "MyApplication->", making me to add "->" after replacing the name.
Is there any editor setting that I have missed in IDE options or is it hardcoded in?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Andreas Hausladen's DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/). It will give you this among many other things. And don't forget his VCL and IDE fix packs...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.  I've gotten into the habit of just letting go of the CTRL key and cursoring left two spaces when this occurs.